# Share auto-incremented primary key between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I want to have two tables each have an INT "id" column which will auto-increment but I don't want either "id" columns to ever share the same number. What is this called and what's the best way to do it? Sequence? Iterator? Index? Incrementor?

Motivation: we're migrating from one schema to a another and have a web-page that reads both tables and shows the (int) ID, but I can't have the same ID used for both tables.

I'm using SQL Server 9.0.3068.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add why that would be required please? There may be a better design which wouldn't require the use of GUIDs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just configure the identity increment to be >1 e.g. table one uses IDENTITY (1, 10) [1,11,21...] and table two uses IDENTITY (2, 10) [2,12,22...]. This will also give you some room for expansion if needed later.

Comment: How exactly do I do this? Is there is anyway to do this using PHPMyadmin?

Comment: Also consider using a bigint when doing this.

Comment: Be aware of the fact that with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` a value can be inserted that would not be issued as an auto number. You can prevent that with a check constraint: `alter table foo add check (Id % 10 = 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

I think using a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid) would be the most straightforward way, if I understand you correctly.

```
SELECT NEWID()
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it needs to be an int.

Answer (score 2):

Use a column with GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) type. It's 16 byte and will be always unique for each row.

Just be aware that you'll get a significant performance hit comparing to normal integer keys.

Answer (score 1):

Use another table with an ID key of type int default it to 1, called KeyID or whatever.

Have a stored procedure retrieve the value, add 1, then update the KeyID, then return this to the stored procedure which is updating your two tables which needs the new unique key.

This will ensure the ID is an int, and that it's unique between the set of tables which are using the stored procedure to generate new ID's.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an IDENTITY column in a third table, use that to generate ID values, but you always roll back any inserts you make into the table (to avoid making it grow).  Rolling back the transaction doesn't roll back the fact that the ID was generated.

I'm not a regular user of Microsoft SQL Server, so please forgive any syntax gaffes.  But something like the following is what I have in mind:

```
CREATE TABLE AlwaysRollback (
  id IDENTITY(1,1)
);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO AllwaysRollBack () VALUES ();
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO RealTable1 (id, ...) VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), ...);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO AllwaysRollBack () VALUES ();
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO RealTable2 (id, ...) VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you would call it.

If you don't want to use a GUID or a separate table, you could also create a function that looked at the max values of the ids from both tables and added one to the that value (or something like that).

You could then call that function in an insert trigger on both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am personally a fan of the GUID solution, but here is a viable option.

Many solutions to this problem have avoided GUID and used good old integer. This is common also with merge replication situations where many satellite sites merge with a master and key conflicts need to be avoided.

If GUID will not work for you, and you absolutely must have int, bigint, or the like, you can always just use an IDENTITY column and have each table with a different value for SEED. Those datatypes have a very wide range, and it is not too hard to split the range into usable segments, especially if all you want is two splits. As an example, basic int has a range from -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) through 2^31 - 1 (2,147,483,647). This is more than enough for a customer table, for example.

**Transact-SQL Reference (SQL Server 2000)**
[int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198(SQL.80).aspx)

Example:

```
--Create table with a seed of 1 billion and an increment of 1
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
primaryKey int IDENTITY (1000000000, 1),
columnOne varchar(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this with an int and you have an auto incrementing number, the way i have done this before is to change the id field auto increment function to the sequence of the other table. I am not too sure in ms sql or my sql but in pgsql that means that in the sql you would have this field

```
 id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_two_seq'::regclass),
```

where table_two_sequence is the sequence function for the other table. Then test it out by inserting some data. I am really sorry if this wont work in ms sql i try to steer clear of it tbh. Failing that the GUID is the best way as has been mentioned by others. Or when inserting in the code that you use you could put an algorithm in that but it could get messy.

Alternatively, think about having the data in one table as this would be a way around it. if you need to you could have a view simulating two tables. Just a thought.

Hope i have helped

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2012 you can declare a sequence object
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx which is exactly what you need.

I should be pretty trivial to emulate a sequence object with a table
containing the next sequence value and a stored procedure atomically 
select the value and increment.  [You'd liked to use function, but functions
can't have side effects.]

How about this hack?  Create a table (MySequence) with two columns: And Identity column (SequenceValue) and a dummy column (DummyValue) and use this stored procedure to get a new sequence value.  The only row in the table will be last sequence value retrieved.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNextValue 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value int = null;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT into MySequence (DummyValue) Values (null);

    SET @value = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    DELETE from MySequence where SequenceValue <> @value

    SELECT @value as Sequence

    return @value
END
```

To use the sequence you'd have to manage the inserts to the target tables--a trigger would probably work.